# How to get id from params in reactjs in a class component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

Here is my App.js where I go to a route having id. Using this I get to AboutComponent. I want to fetch a blog based on that id but unable to get the id in that component.
APP.JS

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

import HomeComponent from './Components/HomeComponent';
import AboutComponent from './Components/AboutComponent';

 function App() {
  return (
  <Router>
  <div>
    <Route path="/" exact component={HomeComponent} />
    <Route path="/blog/:id" component={AboutComponent} />
    
  </div>
</Router>
 );
 }

 export default App;
```

HERE IS ABOUTCOMPONENT.JS. In this, I want to get Id that is in the route and fetch the blog based on that id from my database. I have tried things but could not get what is wrong here. Please help I am new to React Js.

```
  import React, {Component} from 'react';
  import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
  import axios from 'axios';
  import NavbarComponent from './NavbarComponent';
  class AboutComponent extends Component{
   constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
        blog:{}
    }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
    console.log(this.props.match.params);
    let {id}=this.props.match.params;
      axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/blog/${id}`)
      .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      this.setState({ 
      blog: response.data
    });
  
    })
     .catch((error) => {
     console.log(error);
      })
      }
     render(){
     console.log(this.state);
     return(
        <>
        <NavbarComponent />
       {this.state.blog}
        </>
      )
     }
     }

    export default withRouter(AboutComponent);
```

Comment: You are missing `Switch`. `<Router> <div> <Switch> <Route... ... `

Answer (score 1):

You should pass props to the parent Component class by super

Try this

```js
class AboutComponent extends Component{
   constructor(props){
    super(props);

// ...
}
 componentDidMount(){
 let {id} = this.props.match.params;
 // ...
}
}
```

Comment: I tried this but still getting same error. Even I am unable to make the get request using axios.

Comment: Oh you are missing **Switch** at App component

Check example https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start